# java: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to int

Tags: java

I encountered error 'incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to int'

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        switch (i) {

            case (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0):{
                System.out.println("Number #" + i + " :Number is divisible by both 3 and 5" + "--->" + "FizzBuzz");
                break;
                }

            case (i % 5 == 0 && i % 7 == 0): {
                System.out.println("Number #" + i + " :Number is divisible by both 5 and 7" + "--->" + "FizzBuzz");
                break;
            }
```

Comment: `int` expected after `case` but you are using boolean. Better to use if-else instead switch case

Comment: You use `switch` statement wrong. Read here about it: https://www.baeldung.com/java-switch

Comment: i wanted try with switch statement without if else

Comment: This is a situation where if-else is better than switch-case.

Comment: @GfSpa I hope you realize that the switch statement is merely a group of if-else statements in disguise.

Answer (score 2):

The switch statement in Java just does not work like this. You need to use compile time constant expressions in the `case`s, and there are restrictions to what types you can use.

Just use if-statements:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Number #" + i + " :Number is divisible by both 3 and 5" + "--->" + "FizzBuzz");
    }

    if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 7 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Number #" + i + " :Number is divisible by both 5 and 7" + "--->" + "FizzBuzz");
    }
```

If you want to learn how to use the switch statement, see for example [The Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) (or basically any other source you find on the internet by searching "Java switch statement")

Answer (score 1):

Hmm you are getting that error cause you are trying use a boolean operator inside a case statement. In a switch-case statement case must contain the same type as that of switch.

Comment: can you tell mw what i need to change

Comment: Use if/else. You need either int's or String's in a switch statement.